# How to check if a pgfkey has a .code defined?

Tags: pgfkeys

I naïvely wrote this thing:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfqkeys{/pgf}{test/.code={TEST}}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgf/test}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgf/test/.code}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/test}

\end{document}
```

...and I supposed that at least one of the two tests would have given true, but I have:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `\pgfkeys{<key path>/.code=...}` internally defines two keys `<full key path>/.@cmd` and `<full key path>/.@body`, hence you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfqkeys{/pgf}{test/.code={TEST}}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgf/test/.@cmd}{TRUE}{FALSE}  % output "TRUE"

\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgf/test/.@body}{TRUE}{FALSE} % output "TRUE"

\pgfkeys{/pgf/test}

\end{document}
```

There is a short introduction to `<key>/.@cmd` in the pgf manual, sec. 88.3.3.

More Notes

- `\pgfkeysifdefined{<key>}{<true>}{<false>}` tests if an internal command `\pgfk@<key>` is defined, it cannot be used to test if a `<key>` is defined by handler `.code`.
- On the one hand, keys defined by *some* handlers are not distinguishable. For example, `.code` and `.ecode`.
- On the other hand, keys defined by some other (kinds of) handlers are distinguishable. For example, keys defined by `.(e)code` and `.(e)code 2 args` can be distinguished by the argument specification part of their corresponding `\pgfk@<key>/.code` commands.

Comment: I added some limited discussions about how to determine a key is defined by some kind of handlers.